# Соединить 2 файла с условием, Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

У меня есть 2 файла excel, в одном из которых есть список значений (1 скрин), для каждого из которых вам нужно извлечь все значения из другого файла (2 скрин) и получить результат (3 скрин, результат). Желательно использовать pandas. Я уже много пробовал, но я не могу правильно выполнять циклы, чтобы вывести все значения

Первый[image: ][1][1]]

Второй[image: ][2][2]]

Результат[image: ][3][3]]

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: я навёл пример файлов( скриншотами), может кто-то помочь получить в результате (3 скрин)?

Comment: Не надо приводить примеры скриншотами. вы же не хотите, чтобы вам отвечали фотографиями кода? прочитайте первый комментарий к вашему вопросу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже вам нужно получить “декартово произведение”:

```
res = df1.merge(df2, how='cross')
```

Comment: я не совсем понимаю как это сделать, с помощью “декартово произведение”, я смогу подтянуть всё значения 2-го файла, к значениям 1-го ?

Comment: @ValerieOputin, вы пробовали приведённое в ответе решение?

Comment: большое спасибо) как говориться: „Все гениальное — проще простого.“